# facebook get events from page wall

Tags: facebook-graph-api, hyperlink, facebook-page

I am trying to get information about events taking place in a club from their Facebook page. Problem is, that the club doesn't create the events itself. They just post links to the events on their wall. I have troubles accessing the links.

What I tried:

1. `GraphAPI PAGE_ID?fields=posts.fields(link)`

   This returns all posts, but the link field is empty in the posts with link to an event.
2. `GraphAPI PAGE_ID?fields=links.fields(link)`

   This works perfectly, when queried in Graph API Explorer. I get correct links to the events. However, when I use this by php sdk, I obtain only part of the links. The newest link I get is from September, even though there are lots of them after that. All of the links are public. Even if I am logged out, I can see them.

I also tried using **FQL**, but it didn't lead to anything. I am quite convinced, that the second way should work and I can't figure out, why not.

EDIT:

I tried to query directly the links by their ID. When I ask for the link, that I didn't see by the method 2 above, I get "Unsupported get request" error. I think it might be problem with permissions, but I don't understand, why I can get the older links then.

Comment: Have you checked https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/478/

Comment: I thought about paging and it is not the problem. When i specify the query with appropriate 'since', I just get empty array. But this got me to think and I added some additional info to the question.